# Concatenar campos de uma maneira mais performática

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenação-de-string

Estou concatenando as linhas de descrição de um registro para que em vez de ter N registros para uma descrição tenha apenas uma. Eu consigo fazer isso acontecer, mas queria uma maneira mais performática, pois farei isso com uma tabela com uns 900 mil registros.

Um registro para teste criados na tabela temporária #T:

```
SELECT * INTO #T FROM (
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 1 SEQUENCIA, 'ESTE É UM EXEMPLO QUE' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 2 SEQUENCIA, 'EU ESTOU ESCREVENDO NA MÃO' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 3 SEQUENCIA, 'PARA PODER TES-' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 4 SEQUENCIA, 'TAR ESSE TROÇO QUE FIZERAM' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 5 SEQUENCIA, 'EM UM SISTEMA LEGADO E QUE' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 6 SEQUENCIA, 'EU QUERIA DESCOBRIR O MOTIVO DE TEREM LIMITADO ESSE CAM-' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 7 SEQUENCIA, 'PO A 80 CARACTERES SE É UMA DESCRICAO GIGANTE.' DESCRICAO )T
```

Atualmente para fazer esse processo estou usando o **COALESCE**:

```
SELECT  
    TIPO
    ,SUBTIPO
    ,ITEM
    ,CHAVE
    ,COALESCE(
        (SELECT CAST(DESCRICAO AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' AS [text()]
         FROM #T AS O
         WHERE O.CHAVE  = C.CHAVE
         ORDER BY CHAVE,SEQUENCIA
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS DESCRICAO
         into #xablau
FROM #T AS C
GROUP BY TIPO,SUBTIPO,ITEM,CHAVE


--SELECT * FROM #xablau
```

Quero saber se existe uma maneira mais performática de fazer isso no SQL SERVER e como.

Comment: Andrey, já pedimos ao Lucas para dar uma melhorada à resposta. Podes juntar lá mais informação para ela ficar mais completa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo esse [artigo](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation), o método que utiliza **STUFF** é 4 vezes mais rápido que utilizar o **COALESCE**.

Mas existe uma forma ainda mais rápida que é utilizando o **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/)**. Mas acredito que o esforço não valha a pena, visto que a diferença de performance é minima.

Comment: Lucas, apesar do link responder a pergunta é de praxe postar uma parte do que tem no link explicando de forma explicita aqui. Uma vez que o link pode ser desativado e sua resposta ficar sem sentido.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Marconcilio, vou complementar a resposta pra ficar mais completa hoje a noite (Y)

Comment: Não completou D:

Comment: Lucas, podes dar uma melhorada à resposta como referiste?

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra forma seria usar o **STUFF** ele é 4 vezes mais rápido que utilizar o COALESCE, não conheço outras formas que faça isso de forma mais performática que essas duas.

```
SELECT * INTO #T FROM (
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 1 SEQUENCIA, 'ESTE É UM EXEMPLO QUE' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 2 SEQUENCIA, 'EU ESTOU ESCREVENDO NA MÃO' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 3 SEQUENCIA, 'PARA PODER TES-' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 4 SEQUENCIA, 'TAR ESSE TROÇO QUE FIZERAM' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 5 SEQUENCIA, 'EM UM SISTEMA LEGADO E QUE' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 6 SEQUENCIA, 'EU QUERIA DESCOBRIR O MOTIVO DE TEREM LIMITADO ESSE CAM-' DESCRICAO UNION 
SELECT 2 TIPO, 17 SUBTIPO, 1 ITEM,  6546546546546544 CHAVE, 7 SEQUENCIA, 'PO A 80 CARACTERES SE É UMA DESCRICAO GIGANTE.' DESCRICAO )T


SELECT T1.TIPO, T1.SUBTIPO, T1.ITEM,
        STUFF(  
        (  
        SELECT ' ' + T2.DESCRICAO  
        FROM #T T2  
        WHERE T1.CHAVE = T2.CHAVE  
        FOR XML PATH ('')  
        ),1,1,'')  
FROM #T T1  
GROUP BY T1.TIPO, T1.SUBTIPO, T1.ITEM, T1.CHAVE
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta! Mas como o Lucas Venturella ali em cima respondeu com um método ainda mais rapido e um artigo explicando tudo

Comment: Legal, o bom é ter o que você precisa.